# Create an ICO working on XP with python from a PNG or JPG

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-xp, python-imaging-library, ico

ICO created from PNG or JPG with python Pillow are not working on Windows XP. ICO works fine on Vista and later versions.

I wrote a simple code which demonstrate that an ICO which was working on XP and saved with PIL break it on XP:

```
from PIL import Image
original = Image.open('favicon.ico') # you can try with whatever format
original.save('newfavicon.ico') # not recognized on XP
```

I am using Python 2.7.

Do you know if there is anything special with ICO on XP?

Do you have suggestion of other lib I could try?

Comment: I think it worked with PythonMagick... to confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working with Pillow because ICO is saved PNG format, see answer here https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1102

It is working properly with PythonMagick.